# Failsafe Automated Git Update/Add/Commit

Tags: linux, git, bash, command-line, version-control

I have a website that I need to commit system generated files and folders to an existing git repository via linux command line. I have an automated process that monitors a folder for new bash scripts and runs them. The website creates the scripts and saves them to the folder.

I keep getting issues where something has changed on either the remote repo or my local one that is stopping git from completing the following commands

```
git pull --rebase origin

git add [repo path to updated file(s)]/*

git commit -m "commit message"

git push master
```

I need to bullet proof this process so that it will just run and I can forget about it. Right now, permissions issues on files pulled down, or merge conflicts, etc... keep getting the repo out of sync. How can I bullet proof the commands above so they will pull down any remote changes and then commit any new ones necessary?

Comment: If you're getting merge conflicts, I'm not sure you can avoid manual intervention. If the same line changed on remote and local, there's really no way to avoid having a human take a look at it because there isn't any automateable way to decide which change is correct.

Comment: You can avoid permission issues by setting correct permissions manually. (Though you should really find out why the permissions are changing on you in the first place.) Other non-merge issues can, most likely, be dealt with similarly. Merge conflicts, on the other hand and as BlueSpaceCanary indicates, aren't something you can really "automate" unless you can decided to arbitrarily throw away one side of the merge or the other.

Comment: The better question is why are you getting merge conflicts at all. Generating the contents from scratch and fully replacing files you shouldn't really conflict. Unless you aren't making sure you are up to date locally before you generate and commit in which case you should do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over other people editing remote repo files and committing them. I am doing a pull, but I am now considering changing the order of my operation to better facilitate the pull not generating conflicts. I'm thinking that writing the files to a temp directory, doing the pull on the repo, and then copying over the files to the repo and doing the commit will solve this. Any concerns with that approach?

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by writing files to a staging folder, doing an update on the unchanged repo, then moving the files into the repo and committing them.